# Storing Schedule Information

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, sql-server-2014

I need to create a table to hold a schedule for meetings.
A meeting can be scheduled to be:

**Daily**
'Ever X days'. where X can be between 1 and 6.
Ending after X sessions. Where 'sessions' is basically the number of repeats.

**Weekly**
Which days during the week it can occur. Mon, Tue, etc. Can select more than one day per week.
The Date on which it ends.

**Monthly**
Use can select the day of the month it can occur (1st, 2nd etc)
OR they can select from a lookup of '1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th or Last' and a Day 'Mon, Tues', saying, for example "The 2nd Friday" of the month.

How can I store all these scenarios in a single table?

I was thinking:

```
CREATE TABLE schedule
(
   ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
   EndTime TIME NULL,
   RepeatTypeID INT NOT NULL, // Daily, Weekly, Monthly, None
   // For Daily
   EveryDayCount INT NULL, // to handle 'every 3 days',
   RepeatCount INT NULL, // How many occurances. Can be shared with different RepeatTypes
   // weekly
   IsMonday BIT,
   IsTuesday BIT,
   etc // A field per day selection. Is there a better way?
   // Monthly
   MonthlyDayNumber INT NULL,
   MonthlyRepeatIntervalID INT, // Lookup table with '1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, Last'
   MonthlyDayRepeatSelection INT // Lookup on Monday, Tuesday etc
)
```

But this seems inefficient. Is there a better design pattern for these sorts of requirements?

Answer (score 1):

So basically I once implemented the same functionality and I found that rather than ease of storage, that ease of retrieval and edit/update was of paramount importance.

You don't want to calculate all dates every single time, you query the DB for meeting dates or say like you have a function like `showAllMeetingsForADate(somedate date)` then you would not want to calculate  dates for meeting at run time.

Holistically the most optimal storage is that you store meeting information calculation logic in a table and all meeting dates in another table like below.

However for the storage of meeting information, you should go with a normalized form.

**Schedule Detail Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE DailyScheduleDetails
(
  ScheduleDetailsID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  RecurrenceCount INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE WeeklyScheduleDetails
(
  ScheduleDetailsID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  OnMonday bit,
  OnTuesday bit,
  OnWednesday bit,
--  ...
  OnSunday bit,
  EndByDate Date NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE MonthlyScheduleDetails
(
  ScheduleDetailsID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  MonthlyDayNumber INT NULL,
  MonthlyRepeatIntervalID INT, // Lookup table with '1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, Last'
  -- Here I'd suggest using 0 for Last
  MonthlyDayRepeatSelection INT // Lookup on Monday, Tuesday etc
)
```

**Schedule**

```
CREATE TABLE schedule
(
   ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   StartDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
   EndDateTime DATETIME NULL,
   RepeatTypeID INT NOT NULL, // Daily, Weekly, Monthly, None
   ScheduleDetailsID INT
  )
```

**MeetingDates**

```
CREATE TABLE MeetingDates
(
ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
MeetingID int,
MeetingStartDate datetime,
MeetingEndDate datetime -- because you can have meeting spanning days like 11:00 PM to 1:00 AM
--,user or guest information too
,CONSTRAINT FK_MeetingDates_Schedule FOREIGN KEY (MeetingID) 
    REFERENCES Schedule(ID)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an existing standard. That standard is iCalendar RRules and ExDates.

Just store the recurrance rule in the db as a varchar

Use an [existing library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) (C#) to calculate upcoming dates

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have daily, weekly, monthly etc... still means that a meeting will occur on some specific day ... right ?

Thus

```
CREATE TABLE schedule
(
   ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   StartDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
   EndDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
   RepeatTypeID INT NOT NULL, // Daily, Weekly, Monthly, None
   RepeatCount INT NOT NULL,
   DayOn INT NOT NULL, // can be a calculated field based on start date using DAY function
)
```

I believe this can capture all your schedule options.